# Mysterious "multiple definition" error

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

https://gist.github.com/protectivetoast83/25301772cbc6f13e6e07

I moved

```
#include "time.h"
```

from line 2 of *objColPhys.cpp* (which is inherited from *objects.h*) to line 3 of *objects.h*

*time.h* is not included anywhere else in the project, but now I am getting a multiple definition error on line 9 of *time.h*

```
In function `Z7runTimev':
multiple definition of `runTime()'
first defined here
```

also, I don't know what that *Z7runTimev* thing is about since the function is declared as runTime()

What is going on and how can I fix it?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard and 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed all the include guards in your include files (as mentioned in the comments, I will expose it here for clarity).

When you include the same header file in multiple files, the preprocessor just replaces the `#include` directive with all the code in the included file. Therefore, nested inclusions may lead to multiple re-definitions.

This can be solved by simply adding the following code to your include files:

```
#ifndef _TIME_H
#define _TIME_H

// Header file code here

#endif
```

This guarantees that the file is included only once (the rest of the times the preprocessor skips the header file code because of the `#ifndef` directive). You need to add the include guards to all your include files for safety, with the corresponding naming, of course.

Many compilers nowadays support the directive `#pragma once` which you need to add at the beginning of the file, and avoids the hassle of having the ugly `#ifdef`s at the beginning of the file (and of course, that lonely `#endif` at the end)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will add those to my files. I am just a little confused about why I am getting this error in the first place since the _time.h_ file is only included once. **EDIT:** I tried both include guards on time.h and I am still getting the exact same error on the exact same line.

Comment: You need to add it in every header file, also in objects.h: `#ifndef _OBJECTS_H`

Comment: I added header guards to every header in the project and I am still getting multiple definition errors for everything declared in time.h (and only in time.h). I tried changing the names of the items in that file just in case, but I still get multiple definition errors on all of them.

Comment: I kinda figured it out. It looks like the header guards don't like definitions or, apparently, declarations of variables. I removed those from time.h and created time.cpp to put them in and everything compiled.